# Using MonoTouch.Dialog and XibFree together

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have been using MT.D for some time now to make table-based UI layouts. However, I have found that XibFree is awesome for laying out custom pages while keeping the layout code as code (rather than using a designer). This is for (a) easy customization through code and (b) maintainability by other developers.

I would like to use both at the same time. XibFree's table creation isn't as easy to use as MT.D but I can't find a way to extract a UIView from a section and place it into my XibFree layout (all I need is a UIView to do this).

Any ideas? I've tried using the View from the DVC, and the TableView from the RootElement, but no luck with getting either to display in my layout.

Example:

```
new NativeView()
{
    // table view from RootElement - shows empty space where table should be
    View = entryView.TableView
},
```

I've also tried adding a UITableView to my view, and setting the TableView property of the DVC to that, with a call to ReloadData(), with no success.

I was able to get it to load this way:

```
var re = new RootElement ("") {
    new Section("Please Sign In")
    {
        (userName = new EntryElement("User name", "Your user name", "")),
        (password = new EntryElement("Password", "Your password", "", true))
    }
};
var entryView = new DialogViewController (re, false);
//entryView.
var uitv = new UITableView (RectangleF.Empty, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
entryView.LoadView ();
//entryView.TableView = uitv;
re.TableView.Frame = RectangleF.Empty;
uitv = re.TableView;
```

Then in my layout:

```
new NativeView()
{
    View = uitv,
    LayoutParameters = new LayoutParameters()
    {
        Width = AutoSize.FillParent,
        Height = 200
    }
},
```

Which gives me a scrollable region inside the view:
[image]

The region with the lines is its own scrollable view, which I did not expect given I was just giving the area the table view from the one section I created. I want to take the sections out of it and insert them into my view, so there is no scrollable view inside my view. (Never mind the weird look of the UITextfields, I'm using Pixate to style stuff.)

I hope it's just something small I am missing here and that this should be a trivial task.

EDIT: Is there also a way to calculate the height for the rendered section, to give to the LayoutParameters object?